# Doesn't ASP.NET Web Api Model Binding Use Newtonsoft (JSON.NET)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

As far as I understand, Web Api uses Newtonsoft (JSON.NET) serializer/deserializer when model binding. But when I use `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]` attribute for a model property, it does not work. I omit the property in JSON but model binder does not throw exception or make the ModelState.IsValid false. My questions are:

1. Why does it not work if Web Api is using Json.Net? Is there a simple solution like a configuration change?
2. If I have to use a custom model binder in order to use a deserializer that respects such attributes, should my model binder just implement the `IModelBinder` interface or should it inherit from some default model binder implementation?

Comment: No; it uses the DataContract serializer.

Comment: @SLaks How can I make it use Json.Net?