# How do I force .net core 3.1 to deserialize all [FromBody] parameters with Newtonsoft instead of System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net, model-binding

I've done a fair bit of googling to resolve a break after converting an existing 2.1 solution to 3.1.  The default Json serializer changed with the upgrade which shouldn't be a big deal, except I don't necessarily make my json parameter names the same as my properties in all cases.  I've liberally used:

```
[JsonProperty( name = "ALegacyNamedList" , order = 0)]
public List<int> ABetterNamedList { get => aBetterNamedList ; private set => aBetterNamedList = value; }
```

because it's nice for obvious reasons, breaking existing pages not the least of which.  I guess you see what's next; default-ly constructed objects all the way around, because System.Text.Json.Serialization needs a different attribute for a property:

```
[JsonPropertyName( "ALegacyNamedList" )]
public List<int> ABetterNamedList ...
```

So I could go through everywhere and find out where I've named Json parameters a bit different from the class properties for whatever reason.  Or I could get my application to use Newtonsoft instead, right?  There are numerous articles that spell it out.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson;
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    ...
}
```

It took me an hour and 4 articles, and at least half a dozen related posts to get here, but I know it's not using Newtonsoft for the [FromBody] parameters of a controller:

```
[HttpPut("action")]
public string PutSomething( [FromBody] MyObject myObject )
{ ... }
```

where MyObject's property is attributed like

```
    List<int> aBetterNamedList = new List<SomeItems>();

    //[JsonPropertyName("ALegacyNamedList")]  // <-- This works / is not empty
    [JsonProperty("ALegacyNamedList", Order = 0)] // <-- This is default constructed / empty set because it newtonsoft is not used
    public List<int> ABetterNamedList { get => aBetterNamedList ; private set => aBetterNamedList = value; }`
```

So is there another place I need to update so that the pipeline will use the correct tool so that [FromBody] (application/json) content will be parsed not by System.Text but by Newtonsoft.Json?

[Edit] It was recommended that I clarify my post.  I don't want to have to go through all of the code everywhere and change the Request [FromBody] individually, nor go through all of my code and update the working Newtonsoft attributes.  The answer below allows me to change the model binding on a single call.  I want the pipeline itself updated so that all bindings are done using newtonsoft deserialization.

Comment: I had a similar issue like yours and for me it was better to parse the json on and construct the entire class again. That you can do [here](https://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: may be that will help: https://qawithexperts.com/questions/499/how-can-i-set-json-serializer-in-aspnet-core-net-5

Comment: Thanks spzvtbg, I could see that looser rules might help, but the challenge is in the [Attribute] changing, or else in reverting the body parser (which would be much better).

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [How to use json.net for asp.net core model binding on POST requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57892011/3744182).

Comment: Thanks dbc.  Yes that gives me a positive result on a per request level.  Unfortunately it seems instead of identifying every place my json property names differ from my class properties, I would need to identify everywhere in code that I'm doing a [FromBody] parameter deserialization.  That code, applied to a the middleware layer itself rather than the individual requests would be super useful.

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer then.  You might [edit] the title and body of your question and update it with that requirement.

Comment: What makes you so confident that Json.NET isn't used for `[FromBody]` parameters when using `AddNewtonsoftJson()`? I've been using it for years, and I can guarantee that's it's not using `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: Good question, Metoule.  Because Json.NET actually works to deserialize the object.  System.Text doesn't without the [JsonParameterName] attribute, and for the object I've been using for a couple of years now *deserializes as a totally different type!*  It's definitely not Newtonsoft doing the deserialization.

Comment: Thanks, dbc.  I hoped my question was clear enough: So is there another place I need to update so that the pipeline will use the correct tool so that [FromBody] (application/json) content will be parsed not by System.Text but by Newtonsoft.Json?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use this syntax to configure controllers

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
.....

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
           options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
              new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
.....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer comes from this post:  [How to use the json.net...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892011/how-to-use-json-net-for-asp-net-core-model-binding-on-post-requests)  I don't like it because it only works on the [FromBody] tags that you specifically attribute to use the custom model binder.  But it works fine.  Just not a "total" solution, which as clarified at the end of my post would be to use Newtonsoft as the binder in the pipeline before it gets to the method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom model binder to be used when TrackableEntities coming in HttpPost Methods.
/// </summary>
public class TrackableEntityModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

            // Do something
            var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body, bindingContext.ModelType, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
            });

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(value);
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned, it does require updating every put/post where you want to use it:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> 
UpdateDati([ModelBinder(typeof(TrackableEntityModelBinder))] [FromBody] 
Vehicule model)
{
}
```