# WEB API .core 7- Post method Validation

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

SaveEMP method having employee object from body. The employee object have 2 parameters. The method working fine if we pass 2 parameters from Json, but it is also working fine if we pass 3rd parameter along with those 2 parameters

The method public IActionResult SaveEmp([FromBody] EMP emp) should work only if we pass the parameters of EMP from Json. It should give 400 if parameters or more or less

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform this type of validation, you need to inform the JSON serializer as to how you want it to handle missing members when it deserializes into your DTO class. The default behavior is typically to ignore extra members intentionally so that only the tokens you care about are being processed.

Serializers like Newtonsoft provide options like `MissingMemberHandling` that throw an exception when the JSON contains members that don't map to the deserialized class: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeMissingMemberHandling.htm

You could use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package to use the Newtonsoft serializers for your controller model binding:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
});
```

This might throw an exception during the model binding and you can determine whether that exception handling produces a suitable response.

If not, you might consider using a [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding) instead. This would let you explicitly handle the deserialization and specify a failed validation result on exception. There is an example of a model binder invoking this type of behavior in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57909230/13374279

Comment: Can you please provide one sample

Comment: @user3939864 Both approaches have examples, you will have to try them with your code. The linked SA answer is a complete model binder already set up for Newtonsoft deserialization that you might only need to change to use the `MissingMemberHandling` setting during the deserialization and possibly wrap the deserialization operation in a try/catch.