# Newtonsoft JsonConvert per request context

Tags: json.net

I would like to have custom jsonSerializationSettings per api request. On each request there is an offset header value and need to deserialise utc datetime using that custom offset value. I have tried to create a JsonConverter or IsoDateTimeConverter but there is no httpContext available there.

```
class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var context = serializer.Context;
        ...
    }
}
```

the context on JsonSerializer is the StreamingContext.

Any suggestions for a performant solution?

Thank you

Comment: What framework + framework version are you using?  Please specify whether you are using asp.net, asp.net core, or something else, as well as the version.  For instance [How to use json.net for asp.net core model binding on POST requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57892011) applies through asp.net core 2.x but not later, where System.Text.Json replaces Json.NET.